# Delete rows below one in r

Tags: r, dataframe, delete-row

I want to delete rows below a specific one. Let's suppose I have two data frames where I always extract the first value:

```
df1[1,1]
```

[1,1]= 153548

Based on that value which will be found somewhere in the first column of another data frame, I want to keep all rows above that same value and delete everything below.

Comment: Can you edit to provide a simple example of what you have? E.g.: is it like `df1 <- data.frame(one = 153548)` and `df2 <- data.frame(one = c(1,2,3,4,153548,5,6), two=1:7)` and you want to keep only the first 5 rows of `df2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean "keep all rows above the place where that same value is", then maybe you can try

```
df2[cumsum(df2[,1]==df1[1,1])==0,]
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a logical condition to find the row with the cutoff value, then use `cumsum` on the logical vector. The result will be zero for rows above the first appearance of the cutoff value.

```
# Example data
df <- data.frame(x = 1:5,  y = letters[1:5], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
print(df)

  x y
1 1 a
2 2 b
3 3 c
4 4 d
5 5 e
```

Short solution for rows above x == 3

```
df[cumsum(df$x == 3) == 0, ]
```

Result

```
  x y
1 1 a
2 2 b
```

More detailed illustration of the same thing:

```
# Identify the cutoff row
cutoff_value <- 3
df$cutoff_row <- df$x == cutoff_value

# identify rows above and below
df$cumsum     <- cumsum(df$cutoff_row)
df$rows_above <- cumsum(df$cutoff_row) == 0
print(df)

  x y cutoff_row cumsum rows_above
1 1 a      FALSE      0       TRUE
2 2 b      FALSE      0       TRUE
3 3 c       TRUE      1      FALSE
4 4 d      FALSE      1      FALSE
5 5 e      FALSE      1      FALSE
```

Subset

```
df[df$rows_above == TRUE, c("x", "y")]
```

Same result

```
  x y
1 1 a
2 2 b
```